# 999999 Generic Error when converting CSVs to dBase with TableToTable_conversion()

Tags: arcpy, convert, csv, error-999999, dbf

I am attempting to convert 5 fairly large CSV files into DBFs using ArcPy.

My code is below.

Currently when I run this script I am met with the following error:

ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (TableToTable).

Code below:

```
# Convert CSVs to DBase tables in preparation for join to FeatureClass

dir_list = os.listdir(some dir)

boro_list = ["Qn", "Mn", "Bk", "Bx", "Si"]

dir_list = [x for x in dir_list if x.endswith("csv") and x[-6:-4] in boro_list]

print(dir_list)

arcpy.env.workspace = "some dir"

for csv in dir_list:
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(csv, "some gdb", os.path.splitext(csv)[0] + "_dbf")
    print("Successfully converted" + os.path.splitext(csv)[0] + ".csv to " + os.path.splitext(csv)[0] + ".dbf")
```

Printing dir_list prior to defining my env workspace yields a list of the 5 desired filenames for the CSVs. When done in ArcMap I am able to convert without problems using the manual version of the TableToTable_conversion tool.

Comment: You need to specify the input gdb as a raw string, like you're doing for the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

Your output path in Table to Table is wrong in a couple places.
This should fix it:

```
 arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(csv, os.path.join(r"D:\DCP\DataEng\MapPluto\MapPLUTOTest.gdb", os.path.splitext(csv)[0] + ".dbf"))
```

- you have _dbf instead of .dbf
- you didn't have a slash between the output fgdb and the output file name. as-is the name would end up like `MapPLUTOTest.gdbOutputFCName_dbf`

Comment: you need to make the string os.path.join(r"D:\DCP\DataEng\MapPluto\MapPLUTOTest.gdb",.. because you're using backslashes, in this case you *might* get away with it as \D and \M aren't escape characters but if the GDB was called newMapPLUTOTest.gdb there would be problems with \n.

Comment: You're right - I missed the use of black slash (\). I cheated and added `r` to the string to make it correct.